# Rails Actioncable - correct place for subscription?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I'm currently following the official [Rails ActionCable guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html).

It suggests creating a file for the subscriptions (`App.cable.subscriptions.create{...}`) in `app/assets/javascripts/cable/subscriptions/channelname.coffee` - but when I use the command `rails g channel channelname methodname` it creates the corresponding file in `app/assets/javascripts/channels/channelname.coffee`

I've also been following this [guide at nopio](https://www.nopio.com/blog/rails-chat-application-actioncable/), that says it should be a JavaScript file - `app/assets/javascripts/channels/channelname.js`

I'm using Ruby 2.3.3 and Rails 5.0.2. Which place and which filetype is correct?
Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is only one-two string of code. Why to use for that special file. I use react and just place it in my notification component:

```
class Notifications extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.subscribeNofications()
  }

  subscribeNofications = () => {
    this._notificationChannel = App.cable.subscriptions.create(
      { channel: "NotificationsChannel", room: this.getUserChannel() }, {
      received: this.showNotification
    })
  }

  showNofication = (data) => {
    alert(data.message)
  }
}
```

So place it as general code according to your application.